# How to correctly invalidate Redis Cache to maintain consistency

Tags: caching, redis

I am focusing on Cache Invalidation. So when a client update primary data, I am planning to evict the key in the cache so that the next time some client read the data they will need to write back into the cache. This approach seems simple but I envision that there is a possibility that inconsistency might occur.

1. Client A check and see no cached data yet.
2. Client A query primary data and get Version A.
3. Client B update primary data to Version B.
4. Client B brute force removed data from cache.
5. Client A update cache to Version A.

So now the cache contains version A which is incorrect. So how can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you are using cache, you have to endure inconsistence. In your case, normally that's not a problem, since 1) it's not happens all the time, 2) when the data you set in step 5 expires, client can get latest data.

However, you can try the following (more complicated) strategy:

> 4. Client B brute force removed data from cache.

Instead of removing the data, set the data as stale with the new version number. The version number should be monotonically increasing.

> 5. Client A update cache to Version A.

Before updating data in Redis, check version numbers of both data in Redis, and the data to be updated. Do the update if and only if A has a newer/larger version number.

**NOTE**:

1. This is not a perfect solution. Step 4 might increase memory usage, and you should set a small TTL.
2. Step 5 should use Lua script to ensure atomicity.

Comment: Hi, instead of using monotonically increasing number, can I used unique randomly generated version number instead. So instead of comparing newer/larger version number I will just check for mismatched version number. Do you think there is any loophole compared to using increasing version number?

Comment: It depends on whether your data change frequency. If the data changed too fast, old version data might over write new version. For example, 1) A gets version 1, 2) B gets version 2, 3) B updates key in redis, 4) A over writes a new version data